# Conversión Hexadecimal a Decimal C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, conversión-de-tipos, hexadecimal

Estoy convirtiendo un valor hexadecimal a decimal utilizando en primera instancia una función de C#

`numeroResponse = int.Parse(hexaResponse, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);`

donde `numeroResponse` corresponde a la variable `int` en la cual se almacenara el dato y `hexaResponse` corresponde al hexadecimal almacenado en un `string` el problema que tengo es que las primeras 5 o 6 veces que se llama el proceso funciona correctamente, luego de varias pruebas el metodo responde un numero negativo nada parecido al decimal que debería devolver.

Podría tratarse de la función `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber` entonces intente crear el proceso manual utilizando la formula matemática. El método es el siguiente:

```
 private static int hexadecimalDecimal(String hexadecimal)
        {
            int numero = 0;
            const int DIVISOR = 16;

            for (int i = 0, j = hexadecimal.Length - 1; i < hexadecimal.Length; i++, j--) {
                if (hexadecimal[i] >= '0' && hexadecimal[i] <= '9') {
                    numero += (int)Math.Pow(DIVISOR, j) * Convert.ToInt32(hexadecimal[i] + "");
                } else if (hexadecimal[i] >= 'A' && hexadecimal[i] <= 'F') {
                    numero += (int)Math.Pow(DIVISOR, j) * Convert.ToInt32((hexadecimal[i] - 'A' + 10) + "");
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return numero;
        }
```

Sin embargo sigo teniendo el mismo inconveniente, creo que puede deberse a un tema de liberación de memoria o algo así pero la verdad no tengo idea, alguna idea?

Todo esta trabajado en C#

Comment: " luego de varias pruebas el metodo responde un numero negativo nada parecido al decimal que debería devolver." Entonces tenemos que ver ejemplos, porque la funcion siempre devuelve lo que corresponde... Si estas viendo algo asi, hay un problema en otro lado.. necesitamos un [mcve] que haga lo que decis que hace

Comment: La segunda linea es el ejemplo
`numeroResponse = int.Parse(hexaResponse, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);` De esa forma estoy haciendo la conversión donde "Hexaresponde" es el hexadecimal en una variable de tipo string

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo de una manera muy fácil, usando las funcionalidades propias de **.Net**, por lo que te quitarías el trabajo de hacerlo a mano:

```
string numeroHexadecimal = "BEA1";
int numeroDecimal = Convert.ToInt32(numeroHexadecimal, 16);
```

Declaras la **variable** de tipo **string numeroHexadecimal**, que es la que almacenará el **número hexadecimal**, y usando la **función ToInt32** de la **clase Convert** convertimos ese **número hexadecimal** a **decimal**. La **función ToInt32** recibe dos parámetros, un **string** con el **número hexadecimal** y la base que en este caso es **16** (base para trabajar con hexadecimales). De esta forma la **función ToInt32** sabe que debe convertir de un **número hexadecimal** a **decimal**, esta conversión se guarda en la **variable entera numeroDecimal**.

Comment: Gracias, el inconveniente que tengo es que las primeras veces hace la conversión correctamente pero luego me devuelve números negativos en cada conversión.

Comment: @StevenVelasquez, Ok no hay problema solo ve mi respuesta como una solución alternativa que como veras con una línea de código resuelves el problema

Comment: Si muchas gracias, de hecho como mencione al inicio de mi texto inicialmente lo realice en una sola linea de codigo pero al encontrar el problema de que solo en ciertas ocasiones me devuelve el decimal correcto mi segunda alternativa fue hacer el proceso largo.

Comment: @StevenVelasquez, prueba mi respuesta y dime